# Haskell, create function dependent on given type?

Tags: haskell, types

i want to ask if somebody could explain me how the typ declaration works in Haskell(for more complex functions).

I want to create a function that will use exactly these typs:

```
  1)     ([a], a-> a -> a -> b) -> b
  2)     (a -> b) c -> (c ->a) -> b
```

but i dont understand how to read something like that `a->a->a-> b` (i know that b is the output).

Maybe you could help me to read and create a function that match the given typ.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it is very unclear. A function can not have two types, and in particular not the ones which have been posted. Further, `(a -> b) c -> (c ->a) -> b` is not even a well-formed type. The types used below in the tests appear to be entirely something else.

Comment: The attempted definition of `test1`, for instance, appears to assume that `([a], a -> a -> a -> b)` and `([a], a, a, a, b)` are the same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can assume `a-> a -> a -> b` as a function that takes 3 arguments of the same type and generates output of another type.  For example

```
fromRGBtoColor :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Color
```

let's continue specializing to `Int` and `Color` (for generic types `a` and `b`)

Your first example

```
([a], a -> a -> a -> b) -> b
```

is taking a tuple of `[Int]` and function of the same type `fromRGBtoColor` and produces a `Color`.

Your second case is missing some characters..